# Getting 500 error instead of 404 when add slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I didn't find which of the rules cause this bug, my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ru\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/ru\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^en\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/en\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^it\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/it\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^fr\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/fr\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^de\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/de\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^uk\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/uk\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^es\/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/es\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,R=404,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /en/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error_page.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_page.html
```

When I try to open the page which is not exist - it gave me 404 error, but if I add "/" to the existing page - Internal Server Error + error opening /error_page.html file... Why?

Exaple:

```
http://www.example.com/en/cinque-terre-beaches - real page
http://www.example.com/en/cinque-terre-beachesfdsfs/ - 404
http://www.example.com/en/cinque-terre-beaches/ - 500
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your php rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,R=404,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

And move this after other `R=301` rules.

Comment: With this change http://www.incinqueterre.com/de/cinque-terre-beaches.phpSLASH does redirect to the index (why?) and http://www.incinqueterre.com/de/cinque-terre-beachesSLASH exists (ok, I'll use canonical url to fix this). Oh I can't find a way to create nice redirections without double pages

Comment: Why are you sending `\.php` URL. This above rule is for handling `http://www.incinqueterre.com/de/cinque-terre-beaches` and `http://www.incinqueterre.com/de/cinque-terre-beaches/`

Comment: I want that any page that doesn't exist returns 404 error. Would be nice to have 1 url for every page

Comment: Something is missing in the new rule, it gave me a blank page with No input file specified. when I try to open *.phpSLASHsomething and 500 error when I try to open page.php which exists

Comment: Nothing wrong with current rule, it will show 404 for any direct request for `.php`. You should paste your latest .htaccess in your question

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question, but it gives me another error, ex: http://www.incinqueterre.com/fr/manarola.php (I think its better to use 301 redirect for .php requests in this case instead of an error).

Comment: Can you move my 404 rule as your first rule (just below `RewriteEngine on`) line and retry.